# Use variable in activiti

Tags: java, groovy, vaadin, activiti, bpmn

I am playing around with vaadin and activity, and was wondering how to use a variable, in my vaadin code, in my activiti script.  For example my vaadin code is as following

```
TextField field = new TextField("Enter Name: ");
Button button = new Button("Click Me: ");
button.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {

        ProcessEngine processEngine = ProcessEngines.getDefaultProcessEngine();


        RepositoryService repositoryService = processEngine.getRepositoryService();
        repositoryService.createDeployment()
            .addClasspathResource("hello_world.bpmn20.xml")
            .deploy();

        HashMap<String, Object> v = new HashMap<String, Object> ();
        v.put("name", field.getValue());

        RuntimeService runtimeService = processEngine.getRuntimeService();
        runtimeService.startProcessInstanceByKey("myProcess", v);



    }
});
```

and my groovy script in activiti is

```
System.out.println("Hello " + v);
```

I tried to use the `HashMap` but the script still does not recognize my variable.  How do I use my code variables in an activiti script?

Comment: Never used most of the things you're doing, but should that Groovy Script be `println("Hello $name")`

Comment: Groovy is very versatile, so all the functionality in java is in groovy

Comment: Yeah, but you're printing `v`, when it looks like you're setting up a variable called `name`

Comment: woooow, i can't believe that was the problem.  Put that question as the solution and i'll mark you as right

Comment: Done :-) Sometimes you just need another pair of eyes :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're setting up a variable called `name`

```
    v.put("name", field.getValue());
```

But then printing a variable called `v`

```
System.out.println("Hello " + v);
```

If you change this to (making it a bit more Groovy in the process)

```
println "Hello $name"
```

It should work!